# How to get the screen to stop "egg timing", move along while processing code in the background

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a small application express app. It runs some code that takes about 12 mins to execute. (I don't need any help with that side of things, thanks) but what I'm wondering is if there's a means to get the screen to move on, while that code completes?

I have an "After Submit" Process, this is of type "PL/SQL Code" and under the execution options, I have "After Submit." The code is an anonymous block that does some checks and then executes some stored procedures.

The trigger for this is a "NEXT" button in the app. However, the clicking of the "NEXT" button results in a basic 'hang' effect, while the spinny animation "egg timer" thing just runs and runs until the code runs its course.

Is there a way to get the screen to move forward to the next page whilst the code is executed in the background, and the user doesn't have to wait? Thanks!

Comment: Use dbms_scheduler, and have a report that displays the status of those submitted jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure; schedule the procedure as a *database job*. A simple option is to use `DBMS_JOB`. For example, if you put that code of yours into a stored procedure (let's call it `P_SCOUSE`), then you'd

```
declare
  l_job number;
begin
  dbms_job.submit(job        => l_job,
                  what       => p_scouse,
                  next_date  => sysdate,
                  interval   => null);
  commit;
end;
```

The procedure would run in the background, letting you do whatever you want in the Apex application.

Also, check what `DBMS_SCHEDULER` offers. It is newer than `DBMS_JOB`, has some additional options, but - as I said - for such a simple thing, `DBMS_JOB` does *the job*.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.